# Unexpected nextLine() behaviour in Java

Tags: java, input

I'm new to java, the `nextLine();` doesn't work once and it does all of the other times. I'm confused :( I use eclipse in case you need to know.

```
    package tuna;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Calculater {
        public static void main (String args []) {
            Scanner uno = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("How many differant numbers do you want to use? (up to four, minimum two)");
            double two = uno.nextDouble();
            if (two == 2){
                System.out.println("2");
                System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
                double fnum = uno.nextDouble();
                System.out.println(fnum);
                System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
                double snum = uno.nextDouble();
                System.out.println(snum);
                System.out.println("Enter number operation (Say plus, minus, divide or times. No capitials please)");
                String op = uno.nextLine();
```

.                             above the uno.nextLine doesn't work. Why?

```
if (op.equals("plus")){
                        System.out.println(fnum + snum);

                    }


                }
                double three;
                double four;



            }



    }
```

EDIT: What I mean by 'it doesn't work' is that after "Enter number operation (Say plus, minus, divide or times. No capitials please)" is printed in the output, I can't type anything in. When you run it says how many numbers do you want? I type 2 and enter. Then it says enter first number. I say 1 and enter. Then it says enter second number. I say 1 and enter. Then it says what number operation. It doesn't let you type even though there is a nextLine(); in there. If you add another nextLine(); in there you can type, but if you type plus, nothing happens, where it should print the first number add the second number.

Comment: I can assure you it "works as it should", as thousands of users can confirm. If that's not working, that may be YOU doing something wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I've clarified what I meant - see edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you input:

```
3.5<enter>
2<enter>
divide<enter>
```

Then `uno.nextDouble();` consumes `3.5` and leaves

```
<enter>
2<enter>
divide<enter>
```

Then `uno.nextDouble();` consumes `<enter>2` and leaves

```
<enter>
divide<enter>
```

Next `uno.nextLine();` just consumes `<enter>`. You need to call `uno.nextLine();` again in order to consume the remaining `divide<enter>`.

Comment: Oh, okay. I thought that it only reads the input when you press enter, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After you have read what you want from a line, you need to call nextLine() to get the remaining line (even if its empty)